# Send mail with "Send As" or change sender

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0, outlook-2016, email-address

I'm making a script to automate Outlook 2016. I have one account with two different inboxes from clients.

At the end of the script, I need to send an email from the name of the inbox the script is run from. I'm authorized to send email in the name of both inboxes, but I can't get the script to do it. I post my actual code:

## The code:

```
Function Send-Email {
    param ([String]$desde,[String]$subject,[String]$buzon,[String]$inc)


$mail = $Outlook.CreateItem(0)
$firma ="
Textplan
"

$mail.subject = "Closed Ticket "+$subject
[String]$cuerpo =@"
Dear colleague,

bla bla bla

Thank you.
"@

$mail.sender = $buzon
$mail.body = $cuerpo+" "+$firma 
$mail.To = $desde
$mail.Send()
Start-Sleep 3

}

$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$desde = client2@mail.com
$buzon = inbox1@mail.com
$inc = 000000001
$subject = "Automat request"
Send-Email -desde $desde -subject $asunto -buzon $Buzon1 -inc $inc
```

Comment: Is there any reason `Send-MailMessage` is not being used? What happens when you do run your script? Please copy/paste any error messages into the question.

Comment: I see you declared `$buzon` but never use it. -> `-buzon $Buzon1`. Is that a typo?

Comment: @lit Send-MailMessage dont run and the console dont give message but the mail dont go

Comment: @matt $mail.sender = $buzon I use $buzon1 to declare the first inbox, I use 2 inbox, $buzon1 and $buzon2 but I think not necessary write here other steps from the Script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally used this lines and work well:

```
$mail.SentOnBehalfOfName = "inbox1d@mail.com"
$mail.SendUsingAccount = $Outlook.Session.Accounts | where {$_.DisplayName -eq $FromMail}

Function Send-Email {
    param (
        [String]$desde,
        [String]$subject,
        [String]$buzon,
        [String]$inc
    )

    $firma = 'Textplan'
    $cuerpo = "Dear colleague,`r`nbla bla bla`r`nThank you."

    $Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
    $mail = $Outlook.CreateItem(0)
    $mail.subject = 'Closed Ticket ' + $subject
    $mail.sender = $buzon
    $mail.body = "$cuerpo $firma"
    $mail.SentOnBehalfOfName = "inbox1d@mail.com"
    $mail.SendUsingAccount = $Outlook.Session.Accounts | where {$_.DisplayName -eq $FromMail}
    $mail.Send()
    Start-Sleep 3
}

$desde = 'client2@mail.com'
$subject = 'Automat request'
$buzon = 'inbox1@mail.com'
$inc = '000000001'

Send-Email -desde $desde -subject $subject -buzon $buzon -inc $inc
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issues look to be:

1. Object defined outside the function it's being used in:

   ```
   $Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
   ```
2. Unquoted strings in variables:

   ```
   $desde = client2@mail.com
   $buzon = inbox1@mail.com
   $inc = 000000001
   ```
3. Mix and match of single and double quotes

   - I'd recommend reading [about_quoting_rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules) to understand the difference as this is quite crucial when using variables within strings.
4. the function param `$inc` is defined has data but is not used for anything?

   - Recommend to remove this if it's not used.

Not specifically an issue, but I've changed the here string (`@" "@`) to a normal string with line breaks (`r`n`)

---

After resolving the issues and tidying the code:

```
Function Send-Email {
    param (
        [String]$desde,
        [String]$subject,
        [String]$buzon,
        [String]$inc
    )

    $firma = 'Textplan'
    $cuerpo = "Dear colleague,`r`nbla bla bla`r`nThank you."

    $Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
    $mail = $Outlook.CreateItem(0)
    $mail.subject = 'Closed Ticket ' + $subject
    $mail.sender = $buzon
    $mail.body = "$cuerpo $firma"
    $mail.To = $desde
    $mail.Send()
    Start-Sleep 3
}

$desde = 'client2@mail.com'
$subject = 'Automat request'
$buzon = 'inbox1@mail.com'
$inc = '000000001'

Send-Email -desde $desde -subject $subject -buzon $buzon -inc $inc
```

I don't have Outlook to test the code, but from checking it over with the [`Outlook.Application`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application) documentation it now seems to be valid.

Comment: I copy and used it. The problem is $mail.sender, this dont work like i want. Dont work and the email is sending with the original Inbox and not with the email inbox from client.

Comment: I don't use Outlook for mail so can't fault find that exact issue, I'd guess that you need to specify the sender in a different way. Maybe the account name, or maybe a different property ([property list here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem))